# Adiabatic expansion of an ideal gas

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

A. For certain ideal gas Cp=8.58 cal/mol-deg. What will be the final temperature and volume when two moles of the gas at 20 degrees celsius and 15 atmosphere are allowed to expand adiabatically and reversibly to 5 atm pressure? Find W, ∆U, and ∆H.
B. Suppose that the expansion takes place adiabatically against a constant pressure of five atm, what will be the final volume and temperature of the given gas?

I already solved part A but I have no clue for part B. Especially on how to get the final temperature and pressure.

Comment: How do I get the final temperature and pressure for part B?

Comment: They tell you the final pressure.  5 atm

Answer (score 1):

In the following answer I am using the physics convention of work done. Where, $W= \int P\mathrm dV$ and the first law of thermodynamics is as follows: $q = \Delta U + W$. If you want answers in the chemistry conventions than just reverse the sign of the work done. Internal energy change and heat change will be same in both conventions.

---

As you said you have done the first part, I will continue with the second.

First of all,

$$
\begin{align}
\hline
C_V&=C_P - R \\
&= \pu{8.58- 2 cal}\\
&= \pu{6.58 cal}\\
\hline
\end{align}
$$

As the process is adiabatic,

$$
\require{color}
\begin{align}
\hline
q&=0\\
\Delta U&=-W\\
nC_V\left(T_2-T_1\right)&=-nRP_{\text{ext}} \left(\frac{T_2}{P_2} - \frac{T_1}{P_1}\right) \\
\color{green} {T_2}&\color{green}=\pu{247.67 K}\\
\hline
\end{align}
$$

Now,

$$
\begin{align}
\hline
W&= P_{\text{ext}} \Delta V\\
W&= nRP_{\text{ext}} \left(\frac{T_2}{P_2} - \frac{T_1}{P_1}\right) \\
\color{green} W&\color{green}= \pu{599.2 cal}\\
\hline
\end{align}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
\Delta U&= -W \\
\color{green}\Delta U&\color{green}= \pu{-599.2 cal}\\
\end{align}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
\hline
\Delta H&= \Delta U + \Delta \left(PV\right) \\
\Delta H&= \Delta U + \Delta \left(nRT\right)\\ 
\Delta H&= \Delta U + nR\Delta T\\
\Delta H&= \pu{(-599.2 -181.32) cal}\\
\color{green}\Delta H&\color{green}= \pu{-780.52 cal}\\
\hline
\end{align}
$$